# How to Pass custom objects using Spring's REST Template

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, rest-client, resttemplate

I have a requirement to pass a custom object using RESTTemplate to my REST service.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
...

requestMap.add("file1", new FileSystemResource(..);
requestMap.add("Content-Type","text/html");
requestMap.add("accept", "text/html");
requestMap.add("myobject",new CustomObject()); // This is not working
System.out.println("Before Posting Request........");
restTemplate.postForLocation(url, requestMap);//Posting the data.
System.out.println("Request has been executed........");
```

I'm not able to add my custom object to MultiValueMap. Request generation is getting failed.

Can someone helps me to find a way for this? I can simply pass a string object without problem.User defined objects makes the problem.

Appreciate any help !!!

Answer (score 34):

[You can do it fairly simply with Jackson](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-3-rest-web-service-provider-and_28.html).

Here is what I wrote for a Post of a simple POJO.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="newobject")
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class NewObject{
    private String stuff;

    public String getStuff(){
        return this.stuff;
    }

    public void setStuff(String stuff){
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }
}
```

---

```
....
//make the object
NewObject obj = new NewObject();
obj.setStuff("stuff");

//set your headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

//set your entity to send
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(obj,headers);

// send it!
ResponseEntity<String> out = restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, entity
    , String.class);
```

The link above should tell you how to set it up if needed.  Its a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: How can i receive this NewObject in the server (ie, the receiver) end??

Comment: @KJEjava48 To receive NewObject in RestController

`@PostMapping("/create") public ResponseEntity<String> createNewObject(@RequestBody NewObject newObject) { // do your stuff}`

Answer (score 0):

To receive NewObject in RestController

```
@PostMapping("/create") public ResponseEntity<String> createNewObject(@RequestBody NewObject newObject) { // do your stuff}
```

Comment: The question is about client side request construction, but your answer regards server side.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 public int insertParametro(Parametros parametro) throws LlamadasWSBOException {
        String metodo = "insertParam";
        String URL_WS = URL_WS_BASE + metodo;

        Integer request = null;

        try {
            logger.info("URL_WS: " + URL_WS);

            request = restTemplate.postForObject(URL_WS, parametro, Integer.class);

        } catch (RestClientResponseException rre) {
            logger.error("RestClientResponseException insertParametro [WS BO]: " + rre.getResponseBodyAsString());
            logger.error("RestClientResponseException insertParametro [WS BO]: ", rre);
            throw new CallWSBOException(rre.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception insertParametro[WS BO]: ", e);
            throw new CallWSBOException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return request;
    }
```